# Having trouble generating WebService artifacts

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws

I'm having some trouble generating the message and response artifacts for my web service. I meet this error in cmd when I try:

> C:\Users\KingMarkMcC\workspace\WebServiceJX>wsgen -cp -keep .
>   WebServiceImp option "-classpath" requires an argument

Here is my `WebServiceInterface`:

```
package CacheServer;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style;

@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style= Style.DOCUMENT)
public interface WebServiceInterface {

    @WebMethod Object get(Object k);
    @WebMethod void put(Object k, Object v);
    @WebMethod void remove(Object k);
    @WebMethod void flush();
    @WebMethod int size();
}
```

And below my implementation of the `WebService`
    package CacheServer;

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.jws.WebService;


@WebService(endpointInterface = "CacheServer.WebServiceInterface")

public class WebServiceImp implements WebServiceInterface{

CacheDataStruct cache;

WebServiceImp(int i){
    cache = new CacheDataStruct(i);
}

//Getting from Cache
@Override
public Object get(Object k){
    System.out.println("GET REQUESTED");
    return getter(k);
}
private Object getter(Object k){
    return cache.get(k);
}

//Putting into Cache
@Override
public void put(Object k, Object v){
    System.out.println("PUT REQUESTED");
    putter(k,v);
}
private void putter(Object k, Object v){
    cache.put(k, v);
}

//Removing from Cache
@Override
public void remove(Object k){
    System.out.println("REMOVE REQUESTED");
    remover(k);
}
private void remover(Object k){
    cache.remove(k);
}

//Getting size of Cache
@Override
public int size(){
    System.out.println("SIZE REQUESTED");
    return sizer();
}
private int sizer(){
    return cache.size();
}

//Flushing Cache
@Override
public void flush(){
    System.out.println("FLUSH REQUESTED");
    flusher();
}
private void flusher(){
    cache.flush();
}

class CacheDataStruct extends LinkedHashMap<Object,Object>{ 
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8892618408950826874L;
    public final int CACHESIZE;
    private final static float loadFactor =0.75f;

    protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<Object, Object> eldest) {
        return size() > CACHESIZE;
    }

    public CacheDataStruct(int cacheSize){
        super(cacheSize,loadFactor,true);
        this.CACHESIZE=cacheSize;   
    }

    void flush(){
        clear();
        System.out.println("Cache has been cleared.");
    }
}
}
```

Any help as to generating the artifacts would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After my analysis, I have picked that the first challenge here lies within your Service Implementation Bean (SIB) **WebServiceImp**. Your SIB is using an invalid constructor : package access contructor, and thus for you to expose your service you need to add a **Public No-arg constructor**.

> As defined by JSR 181, a class annotated with javax.jws.WebService
>   must have a default public constructor. A SIB class must be  a top
>   level class or a static inner class.

Example of SIB constructors:

```
    public WebServiceImp() {}
    public WebServiceImp(int i) {
        cache = new CacheDataStruct(i);
    }
```

After the above changes and probably after compiling(javac CacheServer/*.java), you can run your wsgen command or simply run the below command (while in src folder):

```
     wsgen -cp "." -wsdl CacheServer.WebServiceImp
```

Also find another way of passing your argument rather than using the constructor in SIB, maybe delegate to another POJO the instantiation of an object requiring arg constructor.